# How to automatically move to the next edit text in android

Tags: android

I have a couple of edit text boxes  on a single line. After the user types in a specific number of characters in the first I want to automatically move to the next edit text. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the `Text Watcher` class and then set the focus on the next `EditText` in the `OnTextChanged()` method of the TextWatcher.

In your case, since you have two Edit Texts, say `et1` and `et2`. You can try out the following code:-

```
et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int before, int count) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(et1.getText().toString().length()==size)     //size as per your requirement
        {
            et2.requestFocus();
        }
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int count, int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

});
```

I have not checked out the code myself, but I hope this will help you solve your problem.

Comment: It helped, but I am facing a issue after the second edittext focus is not going to 3rd edittext. I have total 4 edittext.

Comment: What if i have more than 6  edittexts and i want to apply the same code to every ediitext? I don't want to repeat my code for all 6 ediitexts!

Answer (score 27):

There is a simpler way to do this which doesn't involve knowledge of the ids of the EditText views. For use with android:maxLength="1".

```
// onTextChanged
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
{
    TextView text = (TextView)getCurrentFocus();

    if (text != null && text.length() > 0)
    {
        View next = text.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_RIGHT); // or FOCUS_FORWARD
        if (next != null)
            next.requestFocus();

        doSearch(); // Or whatever
    }
}

// afterTextChanged
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

// beforeTextChanged
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                              int count, int after) {}
```

Comment: This is best answer!

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer is good.

I provide new way if you are using RxJava + RxBinding library.

The coding indicate 4 input Edit Text need verify (My case is Active code SMS via Phone - Phone Verify)

```
// Show button Active code when enough fields active code
    Observable<Boolean> mObsPhoneVerify1 = RxTextView.textChanges(db.etPhoneVerify1)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .map(charSequence -> {
                        db.etPhoneVerify2.requestFocus();
                        return charSequence != null && !charSequence.toString().equals("");
                    }
            );
    Observable<Boolean> mObsPhoneVerify2 = RxTextView.textChanges(db.etPhoneVerify2)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .map(charSequence -> {
                db.etPhoneVerify3.requestFocus();
                return charSequence != null && !charSequence.toString().equals("");
            });
    Observable<Boolean> mObsPhoneVerify3 = RxTextView.textChanges(db.etPhoneVerify3)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .map(charSequence -> {
                db.etPhoneVerify4.requestFocus();
                return charSequence != null && !charSequence.toString().equals("");
            });
    Observable<Boolean> mObsPhoneVerify4 = RxTextView.textChanges(db.etPhoneVerify4)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .map(charSequence -> {
                db.etPhoneVerify1.requestFocus();

                hideKeyboard();
                return charSequence != null && !charSequence.toString().equals("");
            });

    disposable = Observable
            .combineLatest(mObsPhoneVerify1, mObsPhoneVerify2, mObsPhoneVerify3, mObsPhoneVerify4,
                    (PhoneVerify1, PhoneVerify2, PhoneVerify3, PhoneVerify4)
                            -> PhoneVerify1 && PhoneVerify2 && PhoneVerify3 && PhoneVerify4)
            .compose(regisObserver(false))
            .subscribe(aBoolean -> {
                db.btnActiveCode.setEnabled(aBoolean);
            });
    busDisposables.add(disposable);
```

Comment: Is there a combined solution with this to achieve in backward focusing as well?
Like. If I clear EditText4 it then Edittext 3 should be focused.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a list of TextViews for which you want to shift focus (like getting OTP input) then the following code will help achieve it in less number of lines

```
TextView otp1 = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.edit_verify_otp1);
TextView otp2 = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.edit_verify_otp2);
TextView otp3 = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.edit_verify_otp3);
TextView otp4 = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.edit_verify_otp4);

/* Assign the TextViews in the array in the order in which you want to shift focus */
TextView[] otpTextViews = {otp1, otp2, otp3, otp4}; 

    for (TextView currTextView : otpTextViews) {
        currTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                nextTextView().requestFocus();
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }

            public TextView nextTextView() {
                int i;
                for (i = 0; i < otpTextViews.length - 1; i++) {
                    if (otpTextViews[i] == currTextView)
                        return otpTextViews[i + 1];
                }
                return otpTextViews[i];
            }
        });
    }
```